# Django CMS placeholder content not showing up on page when i log out from the admin

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-cms

I'm having trouble with placeholders Django-CMS. I have used placeholders all over my templates of my existing project and they seem to work just fine when I'm logged in, I can add and edit plugins but when I log out all the edits don't show up on the templates anymore.

What might be causing this? I have followed the placeholder creation procedure and published all my changes.

Consider the following scenario; I have `{% placeholder "feature" %}` on my template, the plugin is visible on the page and editable but the content only shows up on the website page when I'm logged in.

Comment: And you have definately published the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cache? In your plugin you could add the line `cache = False`, like:

```
    class YourPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
        model = Yourmodel ...
        cache = False
```